# Make index unique of a model in loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

This is what my model looks like

```
  "name": "mClass",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "mClassName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "index": {
        "unique": true
      }
    },
    "mClassUrl": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "mCreatedBy": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "mCreatedAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "default": "$now"
    },
    "mUpdatedAt": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "mDeletedAt": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

i want to make class name as unique. I tried index:{unique:true} but it seems that it is not working as i can still create classes with same name. Please help me on what changes to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, in your **mClass.js** you can do the following:

```
module.exports = function (mClass) {

    mClass.validatesUniquenessOf('mClassName');

};
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is looking for the Loopback v4 solution to this problem. In Loopback v4 you amend the @property annotation with "index: {unqiue: true}":

```
@model()
export class Client extends Entity {

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true,
    },
  })
  name: string;

}
```

Then you must update your schema:

```
npm run migrate
```

or recreate it:

```
npm run migrate -- --rebuild
```

PostgresQL is support and MySQL, too, I guess

Comment: Did you update your schema? `npm run migrate` or `npm run migrate -- --rebuild`? Not every connector is support. I used PostgreSQL. But MySQL is supported, too, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to define index in your model.json:

```
"indexes": {
  "indexName": {
    "keys": {
      "mClassName": 1
    },
    "options": {
      "unique": true
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to run autoupdate on your datasource when the server starts, great place for that would be a boot script, eg. `./server/boot/db-autoupdate.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = async function(app) {
  // this will trigger the database structure update, like creating indexes (which is not handled by auto-migrate module
  await app.dataSources.db.autoupdate();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html):

> id No Boolean Whether the property is a unique identifier. Default is false. See Id property below.

So I'd assume that instead of index: {...}, you have to use id: true.

Comment: `Id: true` is considered as `primary key` which doesn't have any relationship with a property to be unique.